# For a projection $\Pi$, is $\text{tr}(\Pi X)\leq \text{tr}(X)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, projection-matrices

All matrices are finite dimensional symmetric positive semidefinite matrices in this question.

Let $\Pi$ be projection i.e. in its eigenbasis, it is the the identity matrix with some diagonal elements replaced by $0$. Let $X$ be an arbitrary symmetric positive definite matrix. Is it true that

$$\text{tr}(\Pi X)\leq \text{tr}(X)$$

Using the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3061890/99503), I see that it is indeed true that $\text{tr}(\Pi X)\leq \text{rank}(\Pi)\text{tr}(X)$ but I was hoping the rank term could also be dropped.

Comment: Is $\Pi$ orthogonal?

Comment: @Exodd no. Since projectors satisfy $\Pi^2 = \Pi$ and $\Pi$ is symmetric, we have $\Pi^T\Pi = \Pi^2 = \Pi$, not $I$

Comment: Sorry, I meant "orthogonal projection". In this case, it is since $\Pi$ is symmetric

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $X$ is symmetric positive definite, it has a symmetric positive square root. Then, on the Löwner order, $\Pi\leq I$, and
$$
X^{1/2}\Pi X^{1/2}\leq X^{1/2} X^{1/2} =X.
$$
Then
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(\Pi X)=\operatorname{Tr} (X^{1/2}\Pi X^{1/2})\leq\operatorname{Tr}(X). 
$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there a name/reference for the statement "If $A\leq B$, then $X^{1/2}AX^{1/2} \leq X^{1/2}BX^{1/2}$?

Comment: No, you won't find it as anything else than an exercise, since it is so simple. If $x^T(B-A)x\geq0$ for all $x$, then $x^TS^T(B-A)Sx=(Sx)^T(B-A)Sx\geq0$ for any $x$ and any $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can always consider $\Pi$ diagonal, because  $\Pi = QDQ^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal and $Q$ orthogonal, so
$$
Tr(\Pi X) = Tr(QDQ^{-1}X) = Tr(D Q^{-1}XQ) \\
Tr(Q^{-1}XQ) = Tr(X)
$$
and $Q^{-1}XQ$ is still positive semidefinite.

Now, $D$ is just a diagonal of 0 and 1, so for any $Y$ positive semidefinite you have that $Tr(DY)$ is a sum of some diagonal elements of $Y$. But the diagonal elements of $Y$ are all nonnegative since $Y_{i,i} = e_i^TYe_i\ge 0$, so $Tr(DY)\le Tr(Y)$.