# Relationship between $Trace(AB (AB)^T)$ and $Trace(AA^T)$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

I wonder if there is any inequality (or even equality) relating $Trace(AB (AB)^T)$ and $Trace(AA^T)$, where $A, B$ are both general square matrices of dimension $p$, and $B$ is positive semidefinite (thus symmetric). I did not find much discussion on this, and I tried thinking of it in terms of trace as an inner product, but haven't made much progress yet. Any help or pointer to books is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the cyclic property of the trace, one has
$$\operatorname{tr}(AB(AB)^T)=\operatorname{tr}(ABB^TA^T)=\operatorname{tr}(A^T A B B^T).$$
Since both $A^T A$ and $B B^T$ are positive semidefinite (try proving this), one can use the [following inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3061890/323432) for positive semidefinite matrices $C,D$:
$$\operatorname{tr}(CD)\leq \operatorname{tr}(C)\operatorname{tr}(D).$$
Therefore
$$\operatorname{tr}(AB(AB)^T)\leq \operatorname{tr}(A^T A)\operatorname{tr}(BB^T)=\operatorname{tr}(AA^T)\operatorname{tr}(B^2).$$